# LINQ method syntax with where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to convert LINQ query syntax to method syntax but it's not working.

Below is my query syntax

```cs
quotation = (from q in quotation 
             where q.IsQuotation  || !LineCodeUtility.IsNEWQuotation (q) 
             select q).ToList();
```

Trying to convert to method syntax as below but it's not working

```cs
quotation = quotation.Where(x => x.IsNonNEWQuotation || x => !LineCodeUtility.IsNEWQuotation(x))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "not working". The expressions you posted are trivially discernible as not the same. So if by "not working" you just mean you get different results with each, well...duh. Of course you do. If you mean something else, please explain what you actually do mean, including the _exact_ text of any error messages you are getting, what you've done so far to try to fix it, and what _specifically you need help with. Make sure you fix the question so it includes a good [mcve] that illustrates all of this. Hint: try `x => x.IsQuotation || !LineCodeUtility.IsNEWQuotation(x)`.

Comment: Note that in my hint, the `x=>` part shows up only once...for sure that's a syntax error in the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks @PeterDuniho yes there were some syntax errors which I couldn't able to resolve but the above and below solutions worked. I'm bit new to LINQ so couldn't able to resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are equivalent:

```
quotation =
(
    from q in quotation
    where q.IsQuotation || !LineCodeUtility.IsNEWQuotation(q)
    select q
).ToList();

quotation =
    quotation
        .Where(q => q.IsQuotation || !LineCodeUtility.IsNEWQuotation(q))
        .ToList();
```